# Default datetime with Ecto & Elixir

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I've just started working Elixir & Phoenix today, i am trying to add Ecto as a mapper, but i'm having some trouble using time.

This is my model.

```elixir
  schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    field :email, :string
    field :created_at, :datetime, default: Ecto.DateTime.local
    field :updated_at, :datetime, default: Ecto.DateTime.local
  end
```

I'm trying to set the created_at and updated_at per default, but when i try to compile this, i get the following error.

```
== Compilation error on file web/models/user.ex ==
** (ArgumentError) invalid default argument `%Ecto.DateTime{day: 13, hour: 19, min: 47, month: 2, sec: 12, year: 2015}` for `:datetime`
lib/ecto/schema.ex:687: Ecto.Schema.check_default!/2
lib/ecto/schema.ex:522: Ecto.Schema.__field__/4
web/models/board.ex:9: (module)
(stdlib) erl_eval.erl:657: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
```

There is not much help to get in the documentation, what would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: Notice that `default: Ecto.DateTime.local` is going to be expanded at compilation time which is not what you want. As @whatyouhide said, use `Ecto.Schema.timestamps/1` instead.

Comment: How and where would i specify the use of Ecto.Schema.timestamps/1? I guess i'm not gonna state it as a field, since it creates the fields itself?

Comment: @whatyouhide Again thx! I owe you a hug :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`:datetime` is the native Postgres data type for, well a datetime; this data type maps to a two-elements Elixir tuple (`{{yy, mm, dd}, {hh, mm, ss}}`). An `%Ecto.DateTime{}` struct is not a two-elements tuple, hence the compilation error.

You may want to set the type of your fields to `Ecto.DateTime`, it should all work seamlessly.

[Here](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html) is the relevant documentation about primitive types and non-primitive types.

**PS** you may also want to have a look at [`Ecto.Schema.timestamps/1`](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#timestamps/1), which is macro that expands to basically what you wrote manually (it adds the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields and it let's you choose what type they should be, defaulting to `Ecto.DateTime`):

```
schema "users" do
  field :name, :string
  field :email, :string
  timestamps
end
```

Comment: FWIW timestamps doesn't add created_at and updated_at it ads inserted_at and updated_at [source](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Model.Timestamps.html)

Answer (score 16):

Defaults fields names are  `:inserted_at` and `:updated_at` but you can merge with your own field names, passing a keyword list

```
schema "users" do
  field :name, :string
  field :email, :string
  timestamps([{:inserted_at,:created_at}])
end
```

Comment: How to override :update_at? I do not need :update_at in my table but this timestamps looks for 'update_at' columns.

Comment: You can override that column by passing false as a param in the options, e.g.:

`timestamps(updated_at: false)`

Answer (score 6):

You could also consider having the default not be in the schema, but in the migration: `"created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"`