# elixir, ecto, compare time in the where clause

Tags: timestamp, elixir, ecto

When I create a query using ecto in Elixir, I'm not really sure about how to compare time in the 'where' clause.

In the schema part I declare `create_at` as `:datetime`

```
 schema "tenant" do
   field :id, :integer
   field :created_at, :datetime
   # timestamps([{:inserted_at,:created_at}])

 end
```

and the query part is like

```
def sample_query do
  query = from t in Tenant,
    where: t.id == 123,
    where: t.created_at == %Ecto.DateTime{{2015, 4, 27}, {10, 8, 42}},
    select: t
end
```

It seems that the

`where: t.created_at <= %Ecto.DateTime{{2015, 4, 27}, {10, 8, 42, 0}},`

part is of wrong form. Can someone tell me how to do it in the right way please?

PS: about how to define the field `create_at`, the link below gave me the answer

[Default datetime with Ecto & Elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28506589/default-datetime-with-ecto-elixir)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't create a `%Ecto.DateTime{}` struct from a erlang date/time tuple like that. You need to do:

```
def sample_query do
  query = from t in Tenant,
    where: t.id == 123,
    where: t.created_at == ^Ecto.DateTime.from_erl({{2015, 4, 27}, {10, 8, 42, 0}}),
    select: t
end
```

If your time values are coming from somewhere else and you want to create the `%Ecto.DateTime{}` struct yourself you could do:

```
^%Ecto.DateTime{year: 2015, month: 4, day: 27, hour: 10, min: 8, sec: 42, usec: 0}
```

(Note the ^)

Comment: It worked!!! but it seems that i need to define `created_at` like `timestamps([{:inserted_at,:created_at}])` instead of `created_at: :datetime`

Comment: This didn't work for me. I still get "where cannot be cast to type :datetime in query"

I am using ^ and converting erl date to Ecto.DateTime. 

Ecto.DateTime.from_erl(:calendar.universal_time())

Comment: @JB: does it work if you replace :calendar with some valid date tuple? if so you might need to evaluate the :calendar and do the type conversion in another variable, then ^variable in the where clause.

Comment: I believe you need to use `Ecto.DateTime` as your datatype in the schema, not `:datetime`

Comment: what @chrismcg said is true. Posted question here and got answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245703/querying-by-datetime-in-ecto