# Querying by DateTime in Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Here is what I have tried.

```
date = Ecto.DateTime.from_erl(:calendar.universal_time())
query |> where([record], record.deadline >= ^date)
```

I also tried

```
date = Ecto.DateTime.from_erl(:calendar.universal_time())
query = from m in MyApp.SomeModel,
      where: m.deadline >= ^date,
      select: m
```

Both return same message

```
value `%Ecto.DateTime{..}` in `where` cannot be cast to type :datetime in query
```

From what I understand I am supposed to be using Ecto.DateTime in my queries. Maybe I am missing something obvious? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `:datetime` type is a native type and works only with tuples. If you set your column type to `Ecto.DateTime` in your schema, it will be able to work with higher level types like the Ecto.DateTime struct.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Worked great.

Changed:

    `field :deadline, :datetime`

To:

    `field :deadline, Ecto.DateTime`